# Countdown JavaScript, after ajax refresh, will get Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a forum software from China called `Discuz!X`, it got own template engine.

Now I am doing a plugin for the software, I use their `ajaxget` to refresh my certain `Div.id`.

Below is the original forum code for `ajaxget` function:

```
function ajaxget(url, showid, waitid, loading, display, recall) {
     $F('_ajaxget', arguments, 'ajax');
}
```

In my `.htm` file, my coding as below (explanation: this template engine allow I use `$_G[timestamp]` acting like php `timenow()`, so that mean `$_G[timestamp] = timenow();` `{TIMESTAMP} = timenow()` also):

```
<div id="guestlist"><span id="span_guest{$_G[timestamp]}"></span>
<script>
    var guest{$_G[timestamp]}=30;
    function showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}(){
        guest{$_G[timestamp]}--;
        document.getElementById('span_guest{$_G[timestamp]}').innerHTML="Next customers will reach on "+Math.floor(guest{$_G[timestamp]}/60)+"minutes"+guest{$_G[timestamp]}%60+"second";
        if(guest{$_G[timestamp]}<=0){
            ajaxget('plugin.php?id=jnshopheroes&ajax=renewguesttime&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}','guestlist');
            ajaxget('plugin.php?id=jnshopheroes&ajax=renewguest&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&formhash={FORMHASH}','selllist'); 
        }
        setTimeout("showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}()",1000);
    }
    setTimeout("showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}()",1000);
</script></div>
```

Based on my coding, when `guest{$_G[timestamp]}` countdown until `0`, the `ajaxget` will refresh my 2 div id `guestlist` AND `selllist` as well, but  my chrome browser console will show

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at showtimeguest1502438999 (<anonymous>:5:58)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I think maybe when I refresh the guest list, the previous java script for countdown has been disappear, so can't caught the `showtimeguest1502438999`

I also tried the below code, but doesn't working.

```
<span id="span_guest{$_G[timestamp]}"></span>
<script>
    var guest{$_G[timestamp]}=30;
    function showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}(){
        guest{$_G[timestamp]}--;
        document.getElementById('span_guest{$_G[timestamp]}').innerHTML="Next customers will reach on "+Math.floor(guest{$_G[timestamp]}/60)+"minutes"+guest{$_G[timestamp]}%60+"second";
        if(guest{$_G[timestamp]}<=0){
            ajaxget('plugin.php?id=jnshopheroes&ajax=renewguesttime&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}','guestlist');
            ajaxget('plugin.php?id=jnshopheroes&ajax=renewguest&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&formhash={FORMHASH}','selllist'); 
            clearTimeout(showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}); //add here
            clearTimeout(showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}()); //add here
        }
        setTimeout("showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}()",1000);
    }
    setTimeout("showtimeguest{$_G[timestamp]}()",1000);
</script>
```

How to improve my coding as well? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use such a strange id?  id='span_guest{$_G[timestamp]}'.    Usually people use a simple string, like id="guests".  Then you select that element with $('guests').html()

Comment: if I use `<span id='guests'></span>` without some random id, after `ajax` refresh, it will refresh the `<span id='guests'></span>` and continue show the previous and current value.